my code isnt documenting data into the firestore database
so I'm working on a project for college and I need to make a an app for teachers and students so I tried to make it role based signup so it would put in well ordered but the code doesn't document the data I'm able to authenticate but not store in the firestore
the code
import 'package:prepup/authentication_service.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';



class ExpertReg extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpertReg({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExpertReg> createState() => _ExpertRegState();
}
/////////////////////////////////////////
class _ExpertRegState extends State<ExpertReg> {
  final AuthService _authService = AuthService(); // Initialize AuthService

//

//////////////////////////////////////////


  bool _obscureText = true;
  String? _selectedGender;
  DateTime? _selectedDate;
  TextEditingController _dobController = TextEditingController();
  GlobalKey<FormState> formState = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  late final TextEditingController _email;
  late final TextEditingController _password;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    _email = TextEditingController();
    _password = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _email.dispose();
    _password.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(1900),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != _selectedDate) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = picked;
        _dobController.text = "${_selectedDate!.day}/${_selectedDate!.month}/${_selectedDate!.year}";
      });
    }
  }
  ////////***************************************
  void _registerUser() async {
    final email = _email.text;
    final password = _password.text;
    final role = 'expert'; // based on your logic

    try {
      // Register the user with Firebase Authentication
      final UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );

      // Get the newly registered user's ID
      final String userId = userCredential.user!.uid;

      // Create a document in Firestore for the new user
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Customers').doc(userId).set({
        'email': email,
        'role': role,
        // Add other user data as needed
      });

      // Handle navigation or display messages after registration
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('HomePage');
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle registration errors
      print('Error registering user: $e');
      // Display an error message to the user or handle it in another way
    }
  }

so i tried another method which is creating a whole new dart file with a whole new class and calling the class in the signup page of both the student (customer) and the teacher (expert) but it still not working does anybody have any idea how can i get the data to get documented into the firestore database????
the rules
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
        // This rule allows anyone with your Firestore database reference to view, edit,
        // and delete all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
        // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
        // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
        // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
        //
        // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
        // all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied until you Update
        // your rules
        match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2024, 4, 28);
        }
    }
}


Make sure that your Firebase project is properly configured to work with Firestore. Double-check if you have enabled Firestore in your Firebase project and that your app is properly linked to this Firebase project.
Create a collection first with your desired name i.e. Customers with any dummy data, then try calling the _registerUser().

can you please follow up with a snippet from a code i will really appreciate it

@DatMemeboy1 your code seems okay, you have to manually create a collection in your firestore project.
